# how to store file.urls in jquery-file-upload plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am working on jquery-upload-file plugin and trying to get the urls in an array "attractionImgLinks" everything seems good but when I hit the cancel button before or during my upload it gives TypeError: data.result is undefined and when I hit the Delete button it doesn't remove the deleted file's url from attractionImgLinks.
Can you please explain why is this happening? and how to resolve it?

```
jQuery('#attractionimg').fileupload({
        url: List6.attractionimg
    }).bind('fileuploadfinished', function (e, data) {
            jQuery.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                attractionImgLinks.push(file.url);
        });
});
```